# Get a strongly typed list of unique items using LINQ GroupBy() from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by

How can I get a list of unique items using LINQ preferably with `GroupBy()`?

This would be my try:

```
public IEnumerable<Owner> GetAll(int userId)
{
    return _dbContext.Owners.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Text).Select(x => new Owner()).ToList();
}
```

But this got me this run time error:

> The entity or complex type 'CentraVent.Data.Owner' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

I have to say that this was one of my many tries. I can only find examples that return an anonymous type. How can this be done for a strongly typed object?

**EDIT** with a unique list of Owners, I meant it based on the `Text` column. So no record should have the same value for `Text` column. And it doesn't matter which of the duplicates I get.

The Owner table has the following fields:

- Id
- Text
- Color
- UserId

Comment: Why are your grouping but only returning an enumeration of `Owner`?  Are you sure you don't want to do an order by instead or return `Dictionary<string, Owner>`?

Comment: And you actually doesn't use loaded from DB data as you are returning `Owner` object without  grouped data... Is it mistake or it should be?

Comment: @juharr, I want a unique list of Owners based on the Text property. No dictionary or whatsoever.

Comment: @sergey, what do you mean with 'doesn't used loaded from db data'?

Comment: In your code sample you are returning `GroupBy(p => p.Text).Select(x => new Owner())`. But you don't use `x` that has data loaded from DB. If it's a mistake, then you can do `GroupBy(p => p.Text).ToList().Select(x => new Owner(x))`. Then this code will load all grouped strings from DB and create an owner for them, and also this `x` might be used somewhere in Owner. In my example it was passed to constructor

Comment: @Quoter unique in what way?  unique for the `Text` column?  If so which `Owner` for a given `Text` value do you want to return?  Maybe an example of the data and the expected results would make your intent clearer.

Comment: @juharr, unique records by the `Text` column. So if there are any records that have the same value (or more) for Text, I only want 1 of the records not both. And it doesn't matter which one. I'll update my question with a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which `Owner` you want for each unique `Text` value then you can just get the first one

```
public IEnumerable<Owner> GetAll(int userId)
{
    return _dbContext.Owners.Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
        .GroupBy(p => p.Text).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This got me the following runtime error > The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: Changing your `First()` to `FirstOrDefault()` fixed it. But I'm not sure if `EF` is going to the database for every record.

Comment: @Quoter The `FirstOrDefault` should end up as part of the SQL that EF will run on your DB.  That's why it was complaining about using `First`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this?

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Text).Select(x => new { owner = x }).ToList();
```

or

```
.GroupBy(p => p.Text).Select(x => new { owner = x.Owner }).ToList();
```

hard to tell without seeing the data model

Comment: I updated the question with the fields the table `Owner` has.